# Application of modified MVVM paradigm

Tags: unity, c#, architecture

Let's assume a game development company uses a modified version of the MVVM paradigm that includes the notion of a Manager which handles manipulation of the Model.

So, the idea is

- **View** - all frontend stuff, has no conception of the model (for example, TMP objects and buttons in the Unity hierarchy)
- **View Model** - handles manipulation of data from the model to the view, and vice
  versa when there is user input (for example, a class on a view object with reference to a button that watches for `_OnClick` and tells the Model to emit an event, for example, emit `OnIncrementScore` event, and subsequently updates a text field when the Manager responds to the `OnIncrementScore` event and increments the Model's score upwards)
- **Model** - represents the ontology and underlying data of the domain (for example, assume there is a `score` field). Has event declarations, but no logic, and does not manipulate its own data
- **Manager** - a brain that listens for Model events and takes actions appropriately (for example, increments `Model.score` on response to hearing the `Model.OnIncrementScore` event)

I understand this in theory, but **I can't quite wrap my head around how you'd implement the following situation in this paradigm.**

The player sees a scene before them and there are three "hidden objects" that, when clicked, blends the camera to them and opens a popup displaying the name of the hidden object. The popup can be closed and the camera blends back to the default.

---

I am new to this paradigm, so my first thoughts of implementing it are the following.

We create a class to represent the **HiddenObject** and model its data, and then instantiate it in the scene three times (for example, by allowing the class to inherit from MonoBehaviour and throwing the class on three empty GameObjects):

```
class HiddenObject: MonoBehaviour
{
    public string name;
    public bool isFound = false;

    void Start()
    {
        ... // get reference to model
        model.hiddenObjects.Add(this); // add to the model's list of hidden objects
    }
}
```

This representation belongs squarely to the Model layer, and should not encode information about the collider or camera associated with the HiddenObject, since those are squarely frontend things. (I only have the class inherit from MonoBehaviour so that it's easy for designers to instantiate them by dragging them onto a GameObject in the scene hierarchy and setting their name.)

So how does one set this up?

My thinking is to create a **HiddenObjectViewModel** class that has reference to the collider, camera, popup , and associated HiddenObject instance, add that component to empty GameObjects in the hierarchy, dragging the HiddenObject instances into the appropriate fields to make the connections.

Then, add logic to the HiddenObjectViewModel such that on click of the collider, the camera is blended to, the popup is opened with the name set to the associated HiddenObject, and tell the model to emit an `OnHiddenObjectEntered` event. The Manager can watch for this event and respond appropriately (for example, setting `hiddenObject.isFound = true`, checking to see if all the HiddenObjects in the Model's list have been found in order to advance the game state, etc.). This HiddenObjectViewModel class would also watch the popup's back button for click and blend the camera back to the default on click.

---

But something about this doesn't seem quite right to me, and **I am not sure I understand the division of labor properly.**

Like, it seems like we are putting too much logic into the ViewModel, and I am not sure we are allowed to link ViewModel entities directly to Model entities (for example, referencing instances of HiddenObjects in the HiddenObjectViewModels).

**So I am just asking whether what I describe above seems like a proper understanding of the modified MVVM paradigm I describe, or whether there is another, more orthodox way you might capture this use case in this paradigm?**

Comment: Are you sure the Model has events instead of the ViewModel? If the Model has events - as your question says at the time of writing - then yes, the ViewModel must have references to the Model.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that the class `HiddenObject` of which you posted the code above is part of the Model and not the ViewModel? Then why does it inherit from MonoBehavior? I've used MVC and MVVM patterns in Unity in the past where I usually created the model as a set of plain old C# classes and only used MonoBehaviours for their representation in the scene.

Comment: @Theraot, yeah, the convention here is to have the model hold most or all of the events. Thanks for the input <3

Comment: @Philipp, yeah, the `HiddenObject` is purely a model class.

I think you are right that typically you would just use plain old C# classes or ScriptableObjects for model classes.

I only have it inherit from MonoBehaviour so designers can easily instantiate them in scene by throwing them on empty GameObjects and set their properties (for example, name or any other fields that need to be set). Not the best way to do it I guess, but probably orthogonal to the larger question.